# glTexSubImage leads to black texture, while glTexImage works fine

Tags: c++, image, opengl, glsl

When I bind my image using `glTexImage2D`, it renders fine.

First, the code in the fragment shader:

```
uniform sampler2D tex;
in vec2 tex_coord;
// main:
fragment_out = mix(
                   texture(tex, tex_coord),
                   vec4(tex_coord.x, tex_coord.y, 0.0, 1.0),
                   0.5
                   );
```

Using this code, it draws the image:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 
             0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
```

[image: working fine]

But if I bind it via glTexSubImage2D, the texture is drawn just black.

```
glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
               1,
               GL_RGBA,
               width, height);
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                0,
                0, 0,
                width, height,
                GL_RGBA,
                GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                image);
```

[image: not working at all]

When I replace `GL_RGBA` with `GL_RGBA8` or `GL_RGBA16` in the second code, the rendering is distorted.

[image: distorted]

This is the whole texture loading and binding code:

```
GLuint texture; 
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
int width, height;
unsigned char *image = SOIL_load_image(Resource::getPath("Images/2hehwdv.jpg").c_str(), &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGBA);
std::cout << SOIL_last_result() << std::endl;
std::cout << width << "x" << height << std::endl;
glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
               1,
               GL_RGBA,
               width, height);
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                0,
                0, 0,
                width, height,
                GL_RGBA,
                GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                image);

//glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Can someone explain this behavior to me?

Comment: On your `glTexStorage2D()` call `GL_RGBA` doesn't look like a valid sized `internalFormat`.  Try `GL_RGBA8`.

Comment: @genpfault You are right, I just had to only replace `GL_RGBA` with `GL_RGBA8` in `glTexStorage2D` only (not in `glTexSubImage2D`). Can you add this as an answer with some explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
glTexStorage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_RGBA, width, height );
                                  ^^^^^^^ not sized
```

`GL_RGBA` is an unsized format.

[`glTexStorage2D()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexStorage2D.xml)'s `internalFormat` parameter *must* be passed a [sized internal format](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexStorage2D.xml#idp21315128).

A `glGetError()` call after `glTexStorage2D()` [would have returned](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexStorage2D.xml#errors) `GL_INVALID_ENUM`:

> `GL_INVALID_ENUM` is generated if `internalformat` is not a valid sized internal format.

Try a sized format from [Table 1](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexStorage2D.xml#idp21315128) like `GL_RGBA8`.